# Cannot launch Steam client (18.04)

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, steam

SOLUTION: sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-390:i386

Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/users/835363/rob-fargher

> Ubuntu 18.04
>   NVIDIA Proprietary drivers 390
>   Geforce GTX 1050 Ti

When launching Steam it refuses to start. The amazing thing is that it worked before, but when I downloaded Witcher 2 from GOG and installed the required dependencies, Steam just disappeared. I installled Steam again but it wouldnt load due to failing to load driver swrast. I removed Witcher 2 and uninstalled all its required dependencies (the one that wasnt installed beforehand). I also purged Steam and all its data (both manually and by using the apt purge command) and deleted all orphaned libraries and dependencies using Orphaner. Then I installed Steam by apt install steam and this is its output:

```
steam  
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit  
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically  
Pins up-to-date!  
[2018-06-03 09:24:19] Startup - updater built Jun  1 2018 10:51:34  
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check  
[2018-06-03 09:24:19] Checking for update on startup  
[2018-06-03 09:24:19] Checking for available updates...  
[2018-06-03 09:24:20] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version   1527879669, installed version 1527879669  
[2018-06-03 09:24:20] Nothing to do  
[2018-06-03 09:24:20] Verifying installation...  
[2018-06-03 09:24:20] Performing checksum verification of executable files  
[2018-06-03 09:24:20] Verification complete
```

How do I fix this?
I tried using the solution found on
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4665
but it did not work for me.

Comment: Please never resolve a question in the Stack Exchange Network by [edit]ing the resolution into the question body -- this is what "answers" are for.